# Customize browser window on page load

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

Am using the below code to customize the browser window. But the browser window is resized the below mentioned size but the menu bar always show in the present window. How can i hide all menu bar,status bar and etc. Please help me to fix this error.

```
<body onload=" resizeTo(400,300); menubar.visible = false;">
```

Comment: If I ever would accidentially visit your website and it does resize my browser, I would try to find your home and burn it down.

Comment: Many browsers don't allow you to hide the menu bar and so forth, at least not if your page was opened in a browser window that was already open - as a user I certainly don't want you hiding my menu in an existing window, though I don't feel quite as strongly about it as Uwe Keim. Some (definitely not all) browsers will allow you to hide those features in secondary windows opened from your JavaScript.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to do these things? In modern browsers, you don't have full control of these types of things, as they have learned from mistakes in the past. Using `window.open`, you can control some of the window's bars, but it isn't consistent. And you really don't have too much flexibility just customizing the current window on command

Answer (score 0):

What reason do you have for do this?
Anyone of users will not be happy with this when comes to your page and you change behavior of his browser.

If your page should appear after click on some link, I suggest, you should use popup window instead. Popup window will attract user attention too and no one will be annoyed...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove menus et al in an existing window. You can only create a new window without them.